# Url error 403 when requesting with google (java)

Tags: java, google-api, httpurlconnection

I'm having the "famous" error : Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL.
I have to send a lot's of queries (+-2000) to fill my database. However, the 50-100 first work, then all the following trigger error 403. I can't figure out why ...

Here is my code :

```
public static ArrayList<String> querying(String name){
    URL url = null;
    String inputLine;
    ArrayList<String> resultArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader in;
    try {
        url = new URL(s);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
    try {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0");
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            ...
        }
        in.close();
        con.disconnect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

where `s` is :

`"https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={\"id\":\"/en/"+name+"\", \"name\": null, \"type\":\"/base/popstra/celebrity\",\"/base/popstra/celebrity/friendship\": [{\"participant\": [] }] }".replace(" ", "")`

I tried to find some information about this error on the web, but despite what I found (for example "addRequestProperty) it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL in your question suggests you're not using an API key.

- With an API key, you should be able to do 100k/10k reads/writes per day (according to Freebase documentation)
- Without an API key your quota is limited to a much smaller number  and you'll receive a 403 response when you go over. This is to prevent abuse of the API infrastructure so everyone can get a fair share of API requests.

Please follow the instruction on [Getting Started in the Freebase documentation](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_API#Getting_Started) to get an API key.

Comment: Ok thank you.
Still one question, when I have a key, how can I use it in the query above ?

Comment: Once you have a key, you can pass it to any (Google) API using the `key` URL parameter, e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?q=bob&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>` (also from the Freebase docs)

Comment: When I try : 

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?q=bob&key=<MY_KEY> / mqlread?query= ..

I have the following error : {

 "error": {


  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}

But when I try my key with : 
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?q=bob&key=<MY_KEY>

I get : {"status":"200 OK","result":[]}

I don't know why it doesn't work. I followed every step to create the key in the doc.

Comment: According to the error message, the key you supplied is invalid. Try manually constructing a URL and opening it in your web browser. Make it work there, then work it into your code (replacing your sample query with a real query). You might also want to check out the [Android Google API Client for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/Android) so you don't have to care about all the low-level HTTP requests but can just plain old Java objects instead.

Comment: I get the solution : 
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?key=<my_key>&query...